# How to handle client app not having an internet connection temporarily when dealing with a REST API?

Tags: javascript, spring, infrastructure

I have a basic API built using the spring framework. It is a fairly simple REST API for now.

The app that goes out to clients who are registered to use the API will be making requests to and from said API.

However, so far - I haven't really looked into how to consider if that client loses an internet connection for a few hours or whatever, or if our API were to go down for some reason.

From a design point of view, I would imagine we would handle the response from Spring which basically says "There was no response" - use that to assume communication has failed between the two locations for some reason, and then add the request to a queue in order to try again in a little while?

Now, I would google this - I am sure there is information pertaining to this online, but I am not really sure what this problem or solution is even called - or if a queue is even the best way to handle it.

I'm not really looking for a working solution, or code or anything right now - more so some basic spitballing of ideas on how this can be done - best approaches vs not so good ones, etc. Some library and framework suggestions would be cool too.

Maybe Spring has something built in that I don't even know about yet?

The API is built in java, but the frontend app will likely be using javascript I would imagine - as we don't want to build the same app for multiple mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to experiment with cutting edge web technologies service worker might be something interesting for you.

[developers.google.com Codelabs Offline Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/offline/)